# "Select all/Deselect all" in SAPUI5 SelectDialog

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 SelectDialog. It contains multiple entries. Right now, UI5 provides property to clear all the selected values using `showClearButton="true"`
[image]

**What I want to achieve?**
I want to implement similar functionality, to "Select all" entries in the dialog. I know sap.m.tableSelectDialog provides this, but how can I do this in SelectDialog? Possible solutions can include

1. Check box at top, which says "Select/Deselect all"
2. Button in footer of SelectDialog, which says "Select/Deselect all". [image]

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

The SelectDialog's use case is one way binding. 
This means you supply in a list of items and, using the Dialog in the appropriate mode, its function will be to provide you with what was selected (i.e. not for you to manipulate the values of the checkboxes)

Why not use a List within a Dialog (and not a SelectDialog) if you want to achieve this? There is a List Item type if you bind this appropriately

```
<InputListItem label="Your Label">
    <CheckBox selected="true" />
```

that may be of value to you for this purpose?

From the [documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.SelectDialog):

> List structure & selection 
>   The search field triggers the events search
>   and liveChange where a filter function can be applied to the list
>   binding. The growing functionality of the list does not support
>   two-way Binding, so if you use this control with a JSON model make
>   sure the binding mode is set to OneWay and that you update the
>   selection model manually with the items passed in the confirm event.
>   In the multi-select mode of the select dialog, checkboxes are provided
>   for choosing multiple entries. You can set rememberSelections to true
>   to store the current selection and load this state when the dialog is
>   opened again. When cancelling the selection, the event change will be
>   fired and the selection is restored to the state when the dialog was
>   opened.